# Rails 3 CMS recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-3

I typically use rails models and [typus](http://intraducibles.com/projects/typus) as my CMS as it gives the most flexibility, plus typus is just brilliant. I'm starting a new rails 3 app, and typus isn't rails3 compatible yet. I'm looking around for a CMS that'll work in rails 3. I still want to be able to write my views in haml (rather than some custom templating lang) and need total customizability.

In googling, I'm not finding much. Does anyone have any knowledge about something that would fit my needs?

Thanks.

Comment: Rails3 is still fairly new and hasn't gone to GA yet.

Comment: Beta's been out for quite awhile, and it's on beta 3 :)  Are you saying production sites should still use 2.x?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another CMS starting to rise quickly to fill in the gaps for Rails 3 scene is [RefineryCMS](http://www.refinerycms.com/) - [Github](http://github.com/resolve/refinerycms)

Comment: Refinery CMS supports Rails 3 on the master branch now so that link above is broken. Just go directly to http://github.com/resolve/refinerycms

Answer (score 5):

http://locomotivecms.com is one of good CMS

Answer (score 4):

as of yesterday [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com) 0.9.8 supports Rails 3! You can read about the [transition to Rails 3](http://refinerycms.com/blog/refinery-cms-supports-rails-3).

This makes Refinery CMS the first popular CMS to support Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

[Alchemy CMS](http://alchemy-cms.com) works in Rails 3.
The [next_stable](https://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_cms/tree/next_stable) branch supports Rails 3.1.

Comment: Just to be up to date: Alchemy 2.1 was released and has full rails 3.1 support. The next_stable branch is working with rails 3.2

Answer (score 2):

[Ubiquo](http://ubiquo.me) supports Rails 3.2 in the edge branch.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Osmek. With Osmek you can write in any language you'd like, since you interact with your content through an API.  Its a revolutionizing concept to content management, and the idea of flexibility.

Comment: Official release was today: http://refinerycms.com/blog/refinery-cms-supports-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

Lots of helpful Refinery CMS info at http://www.refinerycms.com/guides

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of almost all Rails 3 CMS. http://bitprison.net/rails3-cms-solutions-2011

Answer (score 1):

I develop a Rails 3 Item & Content Managament called [Opal](http://github.com/hulihanapplications/Opal), which may be interesting to some. Here's more info:

- repo: http://github.com/hulihanapplications/Opal
- site: http://www.hulihanapplications.com/projects/opal
- demo: http://opal.demos.hulihanapplications.com

  - login: admin/admin

Answer (score 0):

locomotiveCMS and BrowserCMS both work in Rails 3